# How to avoid concurrent execution of two methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have two `synchronized` methods, each of them is being executed by a different `Thread`.

```
public synchronized ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt);

public synchronized void dbExecuteUpdate(String queryStmt);
```

How can I make sure their execution won't "overlap"?

One solution that comes to my mind is the following:

```
public synchronized ResultSet dbExecute(String queryStmt, boolean isUpdate) {
if (isUpdate) {
    dbExecuteUpdate(queryStmt);
    return null;
} else
    return dbExecuteQuery(queryStmt);
}
```

But it means I would have to change all code used in the whole project. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Your first snippet is just fine (provided both threads use the same object to execute their queries). What do you think synchronized does?

Comment: That said, a relational database has ACID transactions precisely to **allow** concurrent queries to be executed in a safe way. You shoudn't synchronize them. And that won't work anyway as soon as several clients target the same database.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a dedicated synchronization object:

```
class YourClass {
    Object syncObject = new Object();
    public ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt) {
        synchronized(syncObject) {
            // your code
        }
    }

    public void dbExecuteUpdate(String queryStmt) {
        synchronized(syncObject) {
            // other code
        }
    }
}
```

But it's probably better to use a `ReentrantLock`.

```
class YourClass {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt) {
        lock.lock();
        // your code
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void dbExecuteUpdate(String queryStmt) {
        lock.lock();
        // other code
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Actually, since one is a read and one a write, you probably want to use `ReadWriteLock`.

```
class YourClass {
    private ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    public ResultSet dbExecuteQuery(String queryStmt) {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        // your code
        lock.readLock()..unlock();
    }

    public void dbExecuteUpdate(String queryStmt) {
        lock.writeLock()..lock();
        // other code
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

This way you can have several threads reading concurrently:

> [The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no writers. The write lock is exclusive.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I get the an error telling I can't instantiate `ReadWriteLock()` because it's abstract. Maybe I'm importing the wrong library?

Comment: Use `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, it is an implemention of `ReadWriteLock` interface.

Comment: @Robb1 you need to learn to use the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html. It has a section, right at the beginning, called "All Known Implementing Classes". But again, all this is useless? Databases support concurrent transactions.

Comment: @Robb1 My mistake, I posted code that doesn't compile. Added Xingbin Sun's correction.

Comment: Even adding all your locks I keep having errors. I'm starting thinking that may be an XY problem... I'll update my original message with other important information